# window.onbeforeunload: not assigned unless I set a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, breakpoints, timing, onbeforeunload

I am attempting to set a fairly generic OnBeforeUnload handler:

```
    console.log("WCW - Setting browser warning message");

    window.onbeforeunload = function(e) { 
      e.returnValue = "confirmationMessage";
      return e.returnValue;         
    };

    console.log("WCW - onbeforeunload is " +
        ((window.onbeforeunload ? "set":"still null")));
```

I understand all I can do is signal the browser to issue a fairly generic warning.  In a future iteration I may attempt some self-cleanup before issuing the `return`.

My problem is that `window.onbeforeunload` always returns `null` in the console log after this code runs ***UNLESS*** I set a breakpoint on any line (e.g., the first log message) and then just '*continue*' when it stops.  THEN, it works.

[image: Image of the console]

I'm quite sure a "what is wrong" question is pointless, so I'm asking, "do you have any advice on how I can look for what might be the problem?".

I wonder if it's a scope issue? The 2nd log message always says `onbeforeunload` is non-null... But `window` is a global, isn't it, and how would a debugger pause fix that?

NOTES:

- jQuery is available but using `$(window).on('beforeunload'` is subject to the same issues as this code
- adding a delay (`setTimeout`) to set the handler does not help; tried 2, 4 & 9 seconds
- adding a recursive call to add the handler every 4 seconds while the page is open does not result in the handler being set: `window.onbeforeunload` returns NULL in the console all the time
- periodically, I've seen a jQuery core method attached to the event, but it's rare

Comment: What do you think happens immediately after your event handler exits?

Comment: My event handler never runs - the assignment of it to window.onbeforeunload seems not to happen.  What I think happens when my assignment code exits is that whatever the next frame is starts to execute, but I'm not sure why that would invalidate an assignment to a global resource, or why the breakpoint pause would change that.

Comment: What happens immediately after your event handler exits is _the page unloads_. So you handler is running but you don't see the outcome because the browser unloads your page.

Comment: I think you misunderstand the question. If my handler is assigned, the browser presents a generic "Are you sure you want to navigate away?" message.  The problem is that my handler is not being assigned, so this message is not being presented.  You can test this yourself by pasting my code into your browser's console and then refreshing the page.  You'll get the message I'm talking about.

Comment: [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload) from top to bottom to discover the myriad caveats that may be affecting you.

Comment: @RandyCasburn are you not even reading my responses? You are answering the wrong question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187684/discussion-between-user1944491-and-randy-casburn).

Comment: Does your page use any iframes or similar? Is your developer console pointing at the right window for debugging? (Sometimes it will be set to an inner window, a long shot but worth checking).

Comment: Which browser?  Check this: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/origin.html#sandboxed-modals-flag